# Performing Lucene Search query "Contains"

Tags: c#, lucene, lucene.net

I am doing search for documents that contains the text entered by user

It works fine if the searchText don't have any special characters in it.

Below is how i create my QueryParser. :

```
//analyzer is an StandardAnalyzer()
  QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("Text", analyzer);
            parser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
            return parser.Parse(string.Format("*{0}*", searchText));
```

I get the following error if the search text contains any special character in it :

suppose say search text is "bed ["

```
Cannot parse '*bed [*': Encountered "<EOF>" at line 1, column 7.
```

**How can i make my query parser not fail if there are any special characters in search text and also i don't want to ignore the special characters.**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using:

```
QueryParser parser = new QueryParser("Text", analyzer);
parser.SetAllowLeadingWildcard(true);
var escapedSearchText = QueryParser.Escape(searchText);
return parser.Parse(string.Format("*{0}*", escapedSearchText));
```

i.e. escape the search text before building your query.

Hope this helps,

Comment: another thing i want to ask is after doing QueryParser.Escape, will it ignore the special character while querying . I mean will it still search for "bed [" or the QueryParser.Escape will make it to search for only "bed".

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're after here, but I suspect that you're using the standard analyser for index/query.  If that's the case, then yes: these sorts of characters will be silently ignored (or rather, skipped) by the analyser.

Comment: yes i am using StandardAnalyser, whne tested i saw that its ignoring , is there any work around so i can make it work with special characters and not ignore them

Comment: I think you just need to look at the analysers available and make your best choice.  It could be that the simple analyser is a better fit for your use case... hard to tell really.  You might even need to write your own...

Answer (score 0):

Lucene supports escaping special characters that are part of the query syntax. The current list special characters are

- - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \

To escape these character use the \ before the character. For example to search for (1+1):2 use the query:

(1+1)\:2